# Outputting Array (Penny Pitch Game) (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

Having a little trouble.

This program tosses up 5 coins on a board of numbers. The board is displayed as:

1 1 1 1 1

1 2 2 2 1

1 2 3 2 1

1 2 2 2 1

1 1 1 1 1

So I'm having trouble of coming up with a way to output a 'P' or any letter really on the cells the "coin" landed on. I think a boolean would work, not sure though. It would look something like this:

1 P 1 1 1

1 2 2 2 P

P 2 3 P 1

1 P 2 2 1

1 1 1 1 1

A small section of code in this program would then add up the number the coins landed on
(I already did this part)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class PennyPitch{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random gen = new Random();
        int total = 0;
        Boolean p = true;
        int [][] array = {{1,1,1,1,1},
                        {1,2,2,2,1},
                        {1,2,3,2,1},
                        {1,2,2,2,1},
                        {1,1,1,1,1}};
        System.out.println("Press Enter to commence penny operation.");
        String Enter = reader.nextLine();
        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++){
          for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
            System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
            }
        }
    System.out.print("\n");
        for (int row = 1; row < 2; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
        for (int row = 2; row < 3; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
        for (int row = 3; row < 4; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
        for (int row = 4; row < 5; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }

    int penny1 = array[gen.nextInt(5)][gen.nextInt(5)];
    int penny2 = array[gen.nextInt(5)][gen.nextInt(5)];
    int penny3 = array[gen.nextInt(5)][gen.nextInt(5)];
    int penny4 = array[gen.nextInt(5)][gen.nextInt(5)];
    int penny5 = array[gen.nextInt(5)][gen.nextInt(5)];



    for (int index = 1; index < 4; index++){
        if (penny1 == index){
            total = total + index;
            }
        if (penny2 == index){
            total = total + index;
        }
        if (penny3 == index){
            total = total + index;
        }
        if (penny4 == index){
            total = total + index;
        }
        if (penny5 == index){
            total = total + index;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\nPress Enter for total");
    String Enter2 = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\ntotal is: " + total + "\n");
    System.out.print("\nPress Enter to display where the pennies landed");
    String Enter3 = reader.nextLine();


  }
}
```

Comment: You have not quite mastered the concept of the nested for loop yet. Fixing that will help.

Comment: You could maintain two 2d-arrays. One for the numbers and one for the pennies. When printing, check the penny array. If there's a penny, you print `P` instead of the number.